# How do I run this .js code for a Discord bot?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I was given this piece of code for a Discord bot that apparently logs and keeps track of reactions.

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
        console.log(reaction.users);
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

How do I run this? I have practically zero knowledge of coding, minus some scuffed batch stuff. How do I run this and make it work with my Discord server. I've done the base Discord Bot thing where you go to the Discord Bot Dev thing and make a bot user.

Do I run this with batch, Javascript? I've no clue. Do I have to replace anything to make it work? How does this code even work?

Comment: You should really ask the person who gave you the code. They, or the original author if that's someone else, are in the best position to advise you on this.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/

Answer (score 1):

**How to run this file?**
You can run this file by using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/), this is a CLI-driven tool to create great and fast applications, like a Discord Bot. After installing NodeJS on your system, you first need to close every other Command Prompt window (I assume that you use Windows, otherwise it can be called a terminal) 

As second, you need to create a folder with the file in it. So, you can create the folder called `myBotName` and create a file named something.js (You can change something in everything you want)

After this you can 'cd' to the directory where the .js file is located and simply use `node something.js` to run the script.

Before you can run something as this, you need to install the library. Just use `npm install discord.js` to install the proper packages and dependencies

**This isn't working! (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻**
Indeed, that's because you don't have a token specified, you need to replace the 'token' with a token that you can get from [Discord](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/) 

**How can I generate a token?**
1. Click on 'Create an application'
2. Give a name to it, so you can recognize it
3. Open the tab 'Bot' and create a bot
4. Reveal the secret from that page, that is your 'token'

After that you can invite the bot on your server.

**How can I invite my own bot?**
When you want to invite your own bot to join your server, you need to create a OAuth URL so you can give the bot access to the stuff that it needs. 

1. Open the 'oAuth2' tab
2. Within the scopes you need to check 'bot' as the *only* scope
3. After that you can check every permission that the bot needs
4. When you are done you can copy the generated OAuth URL 
5. Open the URL in the browser, select your own server and just hit Authorize

After that your bot is online, and it can do what you want it to do 

**Note:** When you turn off your computer, your bot will turn off. Maybe you can run it on providers like Heroku or on a Virtual Server

Comment: Respect for taking time to answer beginner question and make them feel welcome! +1

Answer (score 0):

To run javascript code install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) then in your command prompt navigate to the folder with your js file in it then type `node your-filename-here`.